# how should i "clean" UIScrollView from content i added by code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

i have this code im using to add some views to my scroller.
and i have a button that i want him to clean all the views i have added.. how should i do it ?
in face the real question is it possible ? if so- how should my "CLEAN" button method should look like ?

```
     for (int i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_KRANOT_IN_LIST;i++){
                UIView *kerenView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 49)];
                UIImageView *KerenBg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aviv-newTryBox"]];

                UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 49);//310 x 72
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(kerenButtonPressed:) 
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [button setTag:i];
                [kerenView addSubview:button];

                NSString *Value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self getTheNameOftheKeren:i]];
                UILabel *kerenName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(48,13, 255, 25)];
                kerenName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                kerenName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;                

                UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DLApollo" size:18];

                [kerenName setFont:font];

                [kerenName setText:Value];

                KerenBg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 49);
                [kerenView addSubview:KerenBg];
                [kerenView addSubview:kerenName];

                kerenView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0+(49*i), 320, 49);
                [ResultScroller addSubview:kerenView];
}
```

UPDATE *****
I just found the answer and its goes like this;
i add this method to my clean button to remove all the subviews from my scroller:

```
for(UIView *subview in [ResultScroller subviews]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"? What does cleaning do?

Comment: Can you post your answer and close this question. thanks

Comment: i did it. i will check it as current tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer and its goes like this:
i add this method to my "clean" button to remove all the subviews from my scroller:

```
 for(UIView *subview in [ResultScroller subviews]) {
     [subview removeFromSuperview]; 
}
```